# When is OLS numerically unstable?

Tags: regression

When is [OLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares) [numerically unstable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_stability)? How can we solve this problem? I do not quite understand what does "numerically unstable" mean. Does it mean that it does not have a closed form solution such that we can only find a local optimum and being unstable means this local optimum keeps changing?

Comment: The stability of least squares solutions depends on the algorithm used to obtain the solution.

Comment: I would say that it means that the estimates can change substantially when uning another sample to re-estimate them.  It can be the case when you have a multicollinearity problem ?

Comment: @fcop I would agree with you if the question was "when is OLS unstable", but the question was specifically about numerically unstable. This is a term typically reserved for the kind of problems touched on by Glen_b. However, multiconlinearity could still cause both kinds of instability, but the problem, and thus the solution, is a different one.

Comment: @Maarten Buis OK I see, it seems that Lennart also thinks in that direction in his answer?

Answer (score 4):

What do we mean by *numerically unstable*?

Say you want to calculate the ODE:

\begin{align}
y'   &= λy,\quad t\Rightarrow 0  \\
y(0) &= y0
\end{align}

And you calculate this with some method (Euler forward, RK-method or whatever).
If you receive a decreasing solution for each step, $h$, and the actual solution is increasing then the error increases. *A method is unstable if the error increases exponentially.*

A **stable** method might look something like this:

[image]
Figure 1.

Where $y(t)$ is the solution, $t$ is the time, and $h$ is given. The red dotted line represents your numerically calculated solution and you can see that the calculated solution converges to the actual solution (blue line)—this is called convergence.

An **unstable method** might look something like this:

[image]
Figure 2. Source: http://virtual.cvut.cz/odl/partners/tut/unit2/node8.html

Where the red dotted line is the numerically calculated solution and the block dotted line is the actual solution.

Now, how can we solve it, you ask.

We can solve it by either lowering the step size, $h$ (which will make the solution take a longer time to calculate), or changing the method. If a method is unsmooth, for example if the integral is very jagged, then implicit methods are useful such as Euler backward. Implicit methods have larger stable span than explicit methods.

We want to analyze the stability of the ODE above with Euler forward.

\begin{align}
y_{n+1} &= y_n + h(f(x_n, y_n)  \\
      &= y_n + h(λy_n)  \\
      &= y_n(1+λh)
\end{align}

For a stable solution $y_{n+1} \rightarrow 0$ if $n \rightarrow \infty$, that is $y_n(1+λh) -> 0$:

\begin{align}
y_n(1+λh) &= y_0(1+λh)^n  \\
          &\rightarrow  \\
 |1+λh| &< 1  \\
-1 &< 1+λh < 1  \\
-2 &< λh < 0  \\
 h &< -2/λ
\end{align}

In other words, you can chose the step size for the method with Euler forward based on the criteria $h < -2/λ$.

#### **Numerical stability in the context of OLS**

In the context of OLS stability the objective is to minimize the error in the function that is being constructed. The function is constructed as:

$$(X^\top X)\hat\beta = X^\top y$$

and small changes in $X$ might affect the solution—make it jagged or unsmoothed. When will this occur? This might occur when there are numbers in X that differ a lot, sometimes order of magnitudes. A common example is putting the year (2001, 2002, etc.) and a small value, for example,  concentration of an atmospheric substance ($3.3\times 10^{.4}, 4.\times 10^{-4}$) in $X$. If you then $X^\top X$ the difference in the values will become huge. How one solves this is a big topic, a common procedure is to normalize the data or perhaps add a variable to $X$, called ridge regression.

**Ridge Regression**

Instead of:

$$(X^\top X)\hat\beta = X^\top y$$

you can use (difference is adding the variable in the parenthesis):

$$\hat\beta= (X^\top X + \Gamma^\top \Gamma)^{-1}X^\top y$$

with this you can try out RMSE vs. ridge parameter and find out which ridge parameter is sufficient and use that value.

Comment: Nice explanation of what numerical instability means for ODEs. Can you make the connection with OLS to answer the OPs question?

Comment: What is the mathematical condition for inverting $X^T X$ to be numerically unstable? Small determinant?

Comment: I took the liberty of editing this to format it using the $\LaTeX$ markdown CV affords. Please ensure it still says what you want it to.